# TweenMax not scrolling smoothly on tablets/smartphones

Tags: jquery, scroll, tablet, gsap, scrollmagic

I using ScrollMagic in my site in order to make an animation. You can see the animation here:
http://jsfiddle.net/VRBG2/2/

And the code I am using you can see in the jsfidde similar to this:

```
 var topToBottom = new TimelineMax()
  .add(TweenMax.to("#section3", 1, {marginTop: "0"}));

 var scene = new ScrollScene({
   triggerElement: "#section1",
})
.addTo(controller)
.setTween(topToBottom);
```

My problem is than on tablets/smartphones, iphone, iPad and Android this animation looks very bad. Is very slow and not smooth at all.
Does anyone see any problem in my code.
And should I use any other plugins for making this to work better in tablets/mobile?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry I cannot make this jsfiddle stackoverflow code work here.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `autoRound:false`

Since you are animating the `margin-top` CSS property, it doesn't animate on a sub-pixel level. By using `autoRound:false` it will animate on a sub-pixel level .. i.e. margin-top: 100.9999px

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zb754q92/

```
var topToBottom = new TimelineMax()
.add(TweenMax.to("#section3", 1, {marginTop: "0", autoRound:false}));
```

`autoRound` is part of [GSAP CSSPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/Plugins/CSSPlugin/)

Taken from [GSAP CSSPlugin Docs](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/Plugins/CSSPlugin/):

> By default, CSSPlugin will round pixel values and zIndex to the closest integer during the tween (the inbetween values) because it improves browser performance, but if you'd rather disable that behavior, pass autoRound:false in the css object. You can still use the RoundPropsPlugin to manually define properties that you want rounded.

If you do not notice a difference on your phone. Then you might consider animating the `y`
property, so this way you have GSAP animate the `translateY()` property. And also use `force3D:true`, so you can animate using 2D or 3D transforms for a smoother animation.

Hope this helps! :)